# Java Assignment, lost on the math

Tags: java

I am really hoping you can help me out. I am completely lost in my assignemnt and I have been in touch with my instructor, but I still do not understand how to approach my problem. The assignment states I need:

Current Maximum of all generated random numbers so far. 
         (Utilize Math class to determine current Max)

Current Minimum of all generated random numbers so far.
         (Utilize Math class to determine current Min)

I know I need these where I currently have Math.max & Math.min at the lower end of my code. I just am clueless on how to implement it and what the numbers represent.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CLASS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdln = new Scanner(System.in);

        final String HEADING_STR = "%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n";
        final String DATA_STR = "%-15s%-15.0f%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n";
        String maxRandomNumberStr; // The maximum random number to be computed (an integer to be parsed)
        String amountRandomNumbersStr; // The amount of random numbers to be generated (an integer to be parsed)
        int maxRandomNumber; // the integer of maxRandomNumberStr
        int amountRandomNumbers; // the integer of amountRandomNumbersStr
        int round = 0; // the first round
        //int theMax = 0; // how to use?
        //int theMin = 0; // how to use?

        System.out.print("Please enter the maximum random number to be used: ");
        maxRandomNumberStr = stdln.nextLine();
        maxRandomNumber = Integer.parseInt(maxRandomNumberStr);

        System.out.print("Please enter the number of rounds: ");
        amountRandomNumbersStr = stdln.nextLine();
        amountRandomNumbers = Integer.parseInt(amountRandomNumbersStr);

        System.out.printf (HEADING_STR, "Round", "Round #", "Curr Max", "Curr Min", "Curr Total", "Curr Avg");

        for (int i=1; i<=amountRandomNumbers; i++) {
            System.out.printf(DATA_STR, round += 1, (Math.random()*(maxRandomNumber)), Math.max(?,?), Math.min(?,?), "1", "1"); // the "1"s are placeholders
        }
    } // end main
} // end CLASS
```

Comment: store the current max and min in a variable and compare new random numbers to current max and min. update as needed

Comment: Also: break the assingment down into smaller chunks, and then write and *test* those chunks before you move to the next part of the assignment.  For example, a routine that finds the largest (max) of a list of numbers.  C. f. [Work Breakdown Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_breakdown_structure)

Comment: please add example with inputs and the desired ourput.its not so clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: How would I go about storing current max and min in a variable? I am thinking a do loop to update the value

Comment: Why did you just delete [the question that I answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844462/java-homework-assistance)???

Comment: I did not intent to, my bad

Answer (score 4):

If I am understanding your problem correctly I think your input for Math.max() and .min() would be the newest random number being compared to the old min/max.  Please see the Math class documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

I think you would need to always save any new maximum/minimum variables and compare them to the new random number each time.

```
int theMax = 0;
theMax = Math.max(newRandomNumber, theMax);
```

This will assign theMax to be the highest of the two numbers.

You can do the same for min.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I used: theMax = Math.max(maxRandomNumber, theMax);   - but I realize when I run the code the maxRandomNumber is always going to be greater. What value do I use to compare against theMax, I am having trouble understanding where the other argument / value to compare against theMax comes from.

Comment: oh.  I meant you need to give the max function your current highest number and your newest number.  Based on the documentation I linked (which I highly recommend you look at) it says that max(x,y) will return the the largest of the two values.  So you need to give it the two you want compared.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you ca do it easily with a Stream.

```
Stream.of(random1, random2, ...).max();
Stream.of(random1, random2, ...).min();
Stream.of(random1, random2, ...).avg();
```